# Rails ActionController::UnpermittedParameters found unpermitted parameter when param present

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following form that is trying to load in checkboxes with labels all regions and allow those to be saved to logos on the Logo form page.

```
= tb_form_for [:admin, @logo],
  remote: true,
  data: { errors: :inline, success: admin_logos_path } do |f|

  = tb_form_errors(f.object, :base)

  = f.tb_text_field :name
  = f.tb_check_box :home_page, class: 'checkmark'

  = f.tb_file_field :logo_photo
  = image_tag @logo.logo_photo, style: 'padding-left: 180px; padding-bottom: 20px;' if @logo.logo_photo.present?

  = f.collection_check_boxes :region_id, Region.all, :id, :name, checked: Region.all.map(&:id) do |x|
    div
      = x.check_box
      = x.label
  = f.tb_save_buttons('Logo', admin_logos_path)
```

The page loads properly but the error cames with saving I end up with

> ActionController::UnpermittedParameters (found unpermitted parameter: :region_id)

Cool so I check my LogosController and I have the following:

```
class LogosController < ApplicationController
 before_action :load_logo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def create
  @logo = Logo.new(logo_params)
  flash[:notice] = 'Created' if @logo.save
  respond_with @logo
 end

 def edit
  respond_with @logo
 end

 def update
  flash[:notice] = 'Updated' if @logo.update_attributes(logo_params)
  respond_with @logo
 end

 private

 def logo_params
  params.require(:logo).permit(:name, :home_page, :user, :region, :logo_photo, :region_id, :user_id)
 end
end
```

I've tried several variations on the first argument being passed:

- @logo.region results in

> found unpermitted parameter: :Region::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f81a79a81e0>

- :region results in

> found unpermitted parameter: :region

- @logo results in

> found unpermitted parameter: :Logo:0x00007f81a34da8

- @logo.region_id ends up with a Bad Request

> expected Array (got Rack::QueryParser::Params) for param `logo'

How do I accurately hit this?

Edit:

From the log:

```
  Parameters: {"id"=>"12"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "perishable_token" = $1, "last_request_at" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "spud_users"."id" = $4  [["perishable_token", "aFl2KBnsphPP4I6CwXO2"], ["last_request_at", "2018-08-31 15:48:15.999796"], ["updated_at", "2018-08-31 15:48:16.000920"], ["id", 1]]
 (5.4ms)  COMMIT
 Logo Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "logos".* FROM "logos" WHERE "logos"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 12], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 Rendering admin/logos/edit.html.slim within layouts/admin/detail
 Region Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "regions".* FROM "regions"
 CACHE Region Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "regions".* FROM "regions"
 Rendered admin/logos/_form.html.slim (111.2ms)
```

Log when submitting the form:

```
Started PATCH "/admin/logos/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-04 09:02:43 -0400
Processing by Admin::LogosController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "logo"=>{"name"=>"Mr-T", "home_page"=>"1", "region_id"=>["", "1", "3", "4", "2"]}, "commit"=>"Save Logo", "id"=>"12"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Logo Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "logos".* FROM "logos" WHERE "logos"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 12], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

ActionController::UnpermittedParameters (found unpermitted parameter: :region_id):

app/controllers/admin/logos_controller.rb:48:in `logo_params'
app/controllers/admin/logos_controller.rb:32:in `update'
```

Comment: Can you post the params that are appeared in the server log?

Comment: I mean the params when you submit the form.

Answer (score 2):

Change ":region" by ":region_id" on "logo_params" like this

```
  params.require(:logo).permit(:name, :home_page, :user, :region_id, :logo_photo,:user_id)
```

Comment: undefined local variable or method `region_id'

Comment: sory, I fixed, try again